# Trying to stream using eventsource through nginx/fastcgi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stream, nginx, fastcgi

I am trying to set up an event stream using MVC.NET, Nginx and Fastcgi.  The streaming works fine for me using xsp4, but I have not been able to get it to work through Nginx and Fastcgi.  My goal is to open an EventSource stream and to downstream data to my website.

I have tried adding the 'ngx_http_upstream_keepalive' module - http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamKeepaliveModule - which is funny because there is "Note - this This will not work with HTTP upstreams" in the module description.  But wait, isn't that the name of the module?  Anyways, maybe I'm confused here.  I have also tried adding 'proxy_buffering off' to my nginx.conf, which also hasn't helped.

I understand this should be fairly easy to do, but I am at a loss. Is there some property I can add to my nginx.conf to make this work?  Or is there something to add to the Response in .NET?

Please help me StackOverflow!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on what I have read here:

http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel

you need to turn off X-Accel-Buffering. Here is some example code:

```
public ActionResult Stream(string id)
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.BufferOutput = false;
    Response.Headers["X-Accel-Buffering"] = "no";
    return View();
}
```

Hopefully the code above fixes your problem.